# Convert imported SVG shape to Bézier/NURBS surface

Tags: bezier-curves, import, file-format, conversion, nurbs-surface

I have a closed Bézier curve created in Illustrator which I've imported into Blender via SVG. I don't want to extrude it, but rather make it a filled surface (at the moment it's just a path) which I can then manipulate. Ideally it'd either be a bezier surface (is there such a thing) or a NURB, but if need be I can work with a mesh. How do I convert it to a more useful Blender object type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the shape 2D and it will be filled.

The shape will still be editable as NURBS.

If you need to convert it to a mesh press ALT+C
[image]

Comment: But what about shaping it by adding curvature along the third axis (in 3D space)? It'd be ideal to do this with NURBS handles rather than with a mesh.

Comment: There are a number of ways to deform the object. Adding a modifier is the easiest (curve, lattice, mesh deform, simple deform, warp) Play with those and find the one that suits your needs.